# ionic button click to change the color of the next column or row of a grid

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ion-grid

I am pretty new at ionic and angular. I made a grid dynamically from a bidimensional array and 2 buttons "next column" and "next row".

```
  <ion-grid >
   <div *ngFor="let row of grid">
     <div  *ngFor="let div of row" class="no-color">
      {{div}}
     </div>
   </div>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-button (click)="SetColorToNextDiv()"> Next Div </ion-button>
     
  <ion-button (click)="SetColorToNextRow()"> Next Row </ion-button>
```

What I am trying to do is to "navigate" in the grid setting a background color to the next column or row when I click the corresponding button starting from the first column of the first row.
Example:

starting with all div 'no-color'.
on click next row button
div 1 in row 1 set class 'ClassColor',all the rest 'no-color'.
click next div button
div 1 in row 2 set class 'ClassColor' , all the rest 'no-color'.
on click next row button
div 2 in row 2 set class 'ClassColor',all the rest 'no-color'. etc etc

what is the best way to achieve it with ionic/angular?
i guess i could do it setting an id attribute in ngfor and then set the class by id like `document.getElementById(id).className = "ClassColor";`  but i am sure there is a better approach.

Comment: Please add some code

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be help.

```html
<div>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of data;let ri = index;">
    <span class="col" [class.selected]="ri === r && ci === c" *ngFor="let col of row;let ci = index;">
      {{col}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`r` and `c` is component's member variable. By adjusting `r` and `c` on button click, you can change selected element.